# C++: Merge two vectors with tuples as element

Tags: c++, vector, merge

I got two vectors which look like this:
`std::vector<std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int, float, Position, MemberOf>>`

First I sorted them with

```
std::sort(vector.begin(), vector.end(), sort_func());

struct sort_func {
    inline bool operator() (std::tuple<unsigned int, float, Position> &element1, std::tuple<unsigned int, float, Position> &element2) {
        if (std::get<1>(element1) < std::get<1>(element2) || (std::get<1>(element1) == std::get<1>(element2) && tau(element1) < tau(element2)))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    unsigned int tau(std::tuple<unsigned int, float, Position> &element) {
        if (std::get<2>(element) == end)
            return 0;
        else if (std::get<2>(element) == in_plane)
            return 1;
        else if (std::get<2>(element) == start)
            return 2;
    }
};
```

Now I got two sorted vectors and I want to merge them in the way, I sorted them.
I've seen, that there is the `std::merge()` method. But I am unsure how to use it in this complex way.

Can someone explain me how I can use my `sort_func` when merging the two vectors?

The final merged list should maintain the sort order. That is the goal.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: What will merge do ? Put final list in sorted order ?

Comment: @P0W: Yes exactly. Sorry I will edit my question regarding this.

Comment: Well the same way you did for std::sort, by providing `sort_func()` as *comp* parameter of [std::merge](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *same* comparison function object in [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge)<sub>see **second version**</sub> too.

```
// v3 - output vector, v1, v2 -> sorted vector
std::merge(
           v1.begin(), v1.end(), 
           v2.begin(), v2.end(), 
           std::back_inserter(v3), 
           sort_func()
           );
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int, float, Position, MemberOf>> v1,v2,dst;
//fill v1,v2 however you did it
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(), sort_func());
std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(), sort_func());
std::merge(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(dst),sort_func());
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge
The function to compare the two instances has to have the signature:

```
bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
```

So you just have to implement it like that:

```
bool cmp(const std::tuple<unsigned int, float, Position, MemberOf> &element1, 
         const std::tuple<unsigned int, float, Position, MemberOf> &element2);
```

There you can call your original function, if you want to. After implementing it that way you should be able to use:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int, float, Position, MemberOf>> dest; // holds result
std::merge(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), 
           std::back_inserter(dest), cmp);
```

And it seems like the compare function parameters have not the correct type, as they are missing the MemberOf part mentioned in your first line.